# What is the correct Cloud SQL connection string syntax for dotnetcore app with Cloud Run?

Tags: api, .net-core, connection-string, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I want to setup a .NET Core web application on Cloud Run with a Google Cloud SQL database. I easily deployed the database which has a public IP on Cloud SQL and my web application with Docker Container on Cloud Run. I can access the database with SQL Server Management Studio without any difficulties and the web app is up and running as expected. The only piece missing is the link between them that allows them to connect.

In my web app, I got a connection string in that format :

```
Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***;User ID=***;Password=***;Pooling=true;Trusted_Connection=false;Connection Timeout=60;Integrated Security=false;Persist Security Info={0};Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

Once I got the **public IP** and the **connection name** from Cloud SQL, how should be **precisely** be the connection string and/or the next steps?

Furthermore, in the connections tab under Cloud Run Service, I added the Cloud SQL connection. This is supposed to configure a Cloud SQL Proxy for me.

Comment: did you check that doc? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy#expandable-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to connect to Cloud SQL from Cloud Run, you must follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#c)

---

You have already made some configurations in the **Connections** tab as stated in the [Configuring Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#configuring) section. You can check the guide for the [Public IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#public-ip-default) since you configured your instance that way, to be sure that all steps were followed.

Briefly, the steps are:

> - [Configure the service account](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/service-accounts)  for your service. Make sure that the service account has the appropriate  [Cloud SQL roles and permissions to connect to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/project-access-control#roles).
>   The service account for your service needs one of the following  [IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-sql-roles):
>
> - `Cloud SQL Client`  (preferred)
> - `Cloud SQL Admin`
>
> *If the authorizing service account belongs to a different project than the Cloud SQL instance, the Cloud SQL Admin API and IAM permissions will need to be added for both projects.*
>
> Like any configuration change, setting a new configuration for the Cloud SQL connection leads to the creation of a new Cloud Run revision. Subsequent revisions will also automatically get this Cloud SQL connection, unless you make explicit updates to change it.
>
> 1. Go to Cloud Run
> 2. Configure the service:
>
>    - If you are adding Cloud SQL connections to an existing service:
>
>      - Click on the service name.
>      - Click on the Connections tab.
>      - Click Deploy.
> 3. Enable connecting to a Cloud SQL instance:
>
>    - Click Advanced Settings.
>    - Click on the Connections tab.
>      [image: Add Cloud SQL connection]
>    - If you are adding a connection to a Cloud SQL instance in your project, select the desired Cloud SQL instance from the dropdown menu.
>    - If you are deleting a connection, hover your cursor to the right of the connection to display the Trash icon, and click it.
> 4. Click Create or Deploy.

---

After you've double checked the steps above, you could continue with the section [Connecting to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#connecting_to). You can follow the steps on the [Public IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#public-ip-default) tab.

> ##### Connect with Unix sockets
>
> Once correctly configured, you can connect your service to your Cloud SQL instance's Unix domain socket accessed on the environment's filesystem at the following path:  `/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME`.
>
> The  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME  can be found on the  **Overview**  page for your instance in the  [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql)  or by running the following command:
>
> `gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]`.
>
> *These connections are automatically encrypted without any additional configuration.*
>
> The code samples shown below are extracts from more complete examples on the GitHub site.  To see this snippet in the context of a web application, view [the README on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/README.md).

```cs
// Equivalent connection string:
// "Server=<dbSocketDir>/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>;Uid=<DB_USER>;Pwd=<DB_PASS>;Database=<DB_NAME>;Protocol=unix"
String dbSocketDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_SOCKET_PATH") ?? "/cloudsql";
String instanceConnectionName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME");
var connectionString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    // The Cloud SQL proxy provides encryption between the proxy and instance.
    SslMode = MySqlSslMode.None,
    // Remember - storing secrets in plain text is potentially unsafe. Consider using
    // something like https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/overview to help keep
    // secrets secret.
    Server = String.Format("{0}/{1}", dbSocketDir, instanceConnectionName),
    UserID = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_USER"),   // e.g. 'my-db-user
    Password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_PASS"), // e.g. 'my-db-password'
    Database = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_NAME"), // e.g. 'my-database'
    ConnectionProtocol = MySqlConnectionProtocol.UnixSocket
};
connectionString.Pooling = true;
// Specify additional properties here.
return connectionString;
```

> Google recommends that you use  [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager)  to store sensitive information such as SQL credentials. You can  [pass secrets as environment variables or mount as a volume](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets)  with Cloud Run.
>
> After  [creating a secret](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#create)  in Secret Manager, update an existing service, with the following command:

```sh
gcloud run services update SERVICE_NAME  \  
--add-cloudsql-instances=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME  
--update-env-vars=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME_SECRET  \  
--update-secrets=DB_USER=DB_USER_SECRET:latest \  
--update-secrets=DB_PASS=DB_PASS_SECRET:latest \  
--update-secrets=DB_NAME=DB_NAME_SECRET:latest
```

See also:

- [GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/main/cloud-sql/mysql/README.md#deploy-to-cloud-run)